how to automatically break a line if necessary, but have the fixed length otherwise in latex
I am trying to write a template where there are places left blank and needs to be filled according to specific situation. I am using

\rule[-0.5 ex]{0.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}

command to draw a line but the problem arises when sometimes the line is near the end of the paragraph but it still stretches to the margin. I need to find a way to automatically cut that off for aesthetic reasons.
Here is the current result of my code


Can you please create a demo-MWE, which compiles, shows the essence of your approach, and some good and bad results? Then we can better understand what could be done. Thank you

I suggest to use a variable length underscore that TeX's line-breaking algorithm can stretch or shrink like a space.
\def\fillin{\leaders\hrule\hskip.5\textwidth
  plus.1\textwidth
  minus.4\textwidth
  \penalty0 }
This can be {\fillin} to as much as 0.1 of the text width
and {\fillin} to much as 0.6 of the text width and beyond.

